# Using custom spinner function on loading data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I bougth a template a few weeks ago.

**The problem is that when the server returns 404 or 401 the spinner ($ionicLoading) never hide.**

I found a .js file that hide the spinner if happens a error or something like that called "spinner.js"

**spinner.js**

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('restaurant')
    .config(function($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($rootScope, $q) {
            return {
                request: function(config) {
                    $rootScope.$broadcast('loading:show');
                    return config;
                },
                response: function(response) {
                    $rootScope.$broadcast('loading:hide');
                    return response;
                },
                requestError: function(rejectReason) {
                    debugger;
                    $rootScope.$broadcast('loading:hide');
                    return $q.reject(rejectReason);
                }
            };
        });
    })
    .run(function($rootScope, $ionicLoading) {
        $rootScope.$on('loading:show', function() {
            $ionicLoading.show({});
        });

        $rootScope.$on('loading:hide', function() {
            debugger;
            $ionicLoading.hide();
        });
    });
})();
```

I put some debugger into this script, but never called when I request data to my server. How can I integrate this script into my controller? Or I have to put it into app.js?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are missing `responseError` in your code.The `400` and `401` returns from the server is `categorised` as responseError.

```
return {
    request: function(config) {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('loading:show');
        return config;
    },
    response: function(response) {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('loading:hide');
        return response;
    },
    requestError: function(rejectReason) {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('loading:hide');
        return $q.reject(rejectReason);
    },
    responseError: function(rejectReason) {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('loading:hide');
        return $q.reject(rejectReason);
    }
};
```